Taylor Series Expansion of $\tan(x)$ Using the Landau Notation to Express the Error Term
The following is the Example 1 from Apostol's Calculus Volume 1 Chapter 7 Section 7.9:

Claim: Prove that $\tan(x) = x + \frac{1}{3}x^3+o(x^3)$
Solution:
We use the Taylor approximations for the sine and cosine.  From part (e) of Theorem 7.8 (shown later), with $g(x) = -\frac{1}{2}x^2+o(x^2)$, we have
$$\frac{1}{\cos(x)}=\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{2}x^2+o(x^3)}=1+\frac{1}{2}x^2+o(x^2)$$ as $x \rightarrow 0$
Therefore, we have
$$\tan(x) = \frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)} = (x-\frac{1}{6}x^3+o(x^4))(1+\frac{1}{2}x^2+o(x^2)) \\ =x+\frac{1}{3}x^3+o(x^3)$$

Theorem 7.8 Part (e):

As $x\rightarrow a$, we have$$\frac{1}{1+g(x)} = 1 - g(x) + o(g(x))$$ if $g(x) \rightarrow 0 $ as $ x \rightarrow a$

Personally, the proof is so brief that I find it extremely difficult to follow.  So far I am unable to understand what is going on.  The application of the theorem is straightforward enough. $$\frac{1}{\cos(x)}=\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{2}x^2+o(x^3)}=1+\frac{1}{2}x^2-o(x^3)+o(o(x^3)-\frac{1}{2}x^2)$$  What I don't get is why the last bit simplifies to $o(x^2)$.  Also I have no idea how to simplify in the second step.  When I do it, I get the extra terms $\frac{o(x^6)}{2}$, $\frac{-o(x^5)}{6}$, $o(x^4)$, and $\frac{-x^5}{12}$ (assuming my algebra isn't a disaster).  I'm really at a loss here.  I would greatly appreciate any help.
P.S.  Presently the book has only introduced little-o using its limit definition.  I would greatly appreciate it if the answers can work within that definition.

$\begin{array}\\
\dfrac{1}{1+g(x)} -( 1 - g(x))
&=\dfrac{1-(1+g(x)( 1 - g(x))}{(1+g(x)} \\
&=\dfrac{g^2(x)}{1+g(x)} \\
&=o(g(x))\\
\end{array}
$
since
$g(x)\to 0$
implies
$\dfrac{g^2(x)}{g(x)}
=g(x)
\to 0
$
so
$g^2(x)=o(g(x))
$.

If I understand correctly, this proves Theorem 7.8 part (e), which is given.  The main point of the example is to prove the first claim I've written about the cubic taylor polynomial of tan(x).
